# .NET Serialized Binary Data With No Source

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, data-stream

I have been working on a project to import data into another program I was using,. When I first started I thought I could use a csv file to import the data. I found out that that was not the case, and said program used a .NET Serialized Binary Data Stream as the input. I thought I could just deserialize this data in C#. That turned out to not be the case.Turns out I am missing the classes and objects that the program serialised. Is there any way to pull the data out of this binary data stream so I can view it and replicate it without using C# to mock the objects and classes? I have already tried to use a hex editor, but the file is to large to manually convert all the values.

Comment: The point of serialization is to convert objects and list into some form of data that can be used to recreate the list/objects.  If you dont have the class(es) your app doesnt have the blueprint.  It may not matter - if it used the `BinaryFormatter` it will only deserialize using the same class-culture-version without some other hoops.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Deserializing a `BinaryFormatter` stream requires you to have the same types present as when serializing.  It's one of the biggest reasons not to use `BinaryFormatter`.  That being said you might take a look at [How to analyse contents of binary serialization stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3052202/3744182).  In fact, is this a duplicate?