# How to automatically deserialize a file that was serialized using BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, xml-serialization, binaryformatter

### Problem

I have a large file that was serialized using `BinaryFormatter` that I need to create a `class` for, so that I can serialize similar files.

### What I have tried

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30176566/17263281) that explains how to do this manually.

However, the file I have is over `500kB`, so this would take a very long time by hand.

### Question

Is there a way to automatically get the structure(s) described within the file?

Comment: You need to use the same classes that were used to serialize.  Do you have the original classes?  It also may need to be done with same Net/Core version that was used to serialize.

Comment: I do not have the original classes.
I started working through using the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30176566/17263281) that I mentioned and was able to get a bit of it loaded. But looking at my progress it will likely take weeks to get through the whole file.

Comment: See following : https://github.com/bbowyersmyth/BinaryFormatDataStructure

Comment: That has helped a lot.
However, I am seeing some variables that have forward slashes (`/`) within the variable name (e.g. `Item5/B`).
This is obviously not possible in C#, and I am having difficulty finding what that could represent.

Comment: I used xml serializer and got following `Item5_x002F_B`

Comment: I tried naming a property `Item5_x002F_B`, but it just put `Item5_x002F_B` into the file when serializing using `BinaryFormatter`. How do I get it to serialize as `Item5/B` instead?

Comment: Don't know.  Maybe `&sol;`

Comment: How would that allow me to serialize the variable name with a `/` in it? I feel like I am missing something here.